# Any way to render templates into a variable with Express3.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, template-engine, hogan.js

in express3.x, the api talks about app.render('view', data, callback);
it is supposed to do the same thing as res.render, but with a callback with the rendered data, instead of sending it as a response.
Is there a way to use app.render in a route file. It's not possible since there is no app variable anywhere but app.js
maybe there is some other easy way to just render a template and store it a variable.
I need it to send html emails.
I'm using hogan.js templates in my app.

Thanks

Comment: There is an `app` property on both `req` and `res` that you can use.

Comment: could you please explain a little further.

Comment: If all you need is the callback, just add it to [`res.render`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render) ... All I was pointing out is that you could use `res.app.render` if you needed access to `app` (which I don't think you even need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write routes and modules in a way that app gets passed when you require

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  return {
    'index': function(req, res, next) {
      // app is avail here 
    }
  }
}
```

and require it accordingly and pass on the app variable in app.js

```
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
var validate = require('./routes/validate')(app);
```

This might not be a standard way, and especially the way the route file is written might be awkward. But it makes app avail. to your routes.

Comment: I was thinking of a way to do this, this just never struck me... This would work perfectly. I'm gonna give it a try

Comment: Happy to serve you. You might wanna check different styles of this, because any tool scanning the source for autocomplete etc will go crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to call the templating engine directly. For example if you use [Hogan.js](http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/) with [consolidate](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js/), you can do this:

```
var hogan = require('consolidate').hogan;

hogan(path_to_template or string, rendering_values, function(err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

I find this better than using app.render, as it is more direct.

Comment: I wanted to use app.render to be able to keep my code independent of the tempting engine, specially as I was trying a few of them for different projects but sharing some parts of the code